# Is there a way to copy the contents of a static file in Sveltekit into a string?

Tags: static, assets, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to build a web app with Sveltekit.

Currently I am working on a simple navigation which should include a text and an icon for each path. I want to generate this dynamically so I am doing this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let currentRoute: string;

    type Route = { icon: string; name: string; path: string };

    const routes: Route[] = [
        { icon: '', name: 'Home', path: '/' },
        { icon: 'icons/servers.svg', name: 'Servers', path: '/servers' }
    ];
</script>

<nav>
    <ul>
        {#each routes as route}
            <li class:active={currentRoute === route.path}>
                <a href={route.path}>
                    <img src={route.icon} alt="" />
                    <p>{route.name}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This all works fine, but I actually want to change the color of the text and the svg when the corresponding `li` tag has the class active (which means it is the current route).
As I am using `img` I cannot change the color directly in css so my thought was to somehow read the static svg files via code and output them to keep everything dynamic.

So the question is: Is there a way to read the contents of each static svg file and just copy them into a variable to keep everything clean?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to go around this.

### svg as a component

One is to make all svg files components on their own, just name the file `Server.svelte` and keep the content of the file itself the same. Then include this component and use it as normal.  This will inline the svg in your html and you can style it as normal.

I always have

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="1em" width="1em" fill="currentColor">
```

this ensures the icon scales with the surrounding text and takes it's color.

(if you don't want to rename the file to .svelte, you can use a plugin to import .svg files as well)

### Refer to an included svg

Another technique is to write ```html

````
This requires you have somewhere else in your html the following

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <defs>
    <g id="myicon">
      <path d="..." fill="currentColor" />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
````

This will do more or less the same as the previous method. How you get all of this included is p to you.  One idea would be to make an `icons.svelte` file with all the icons in it as defenition and include this at the top level.  And another component Icon.svelte that sets up the `xlink:href` block for you so you can simply do `<Icon id="myicon" />` in places where you need an icon